# Plotly displays unnecessary extra values on the x axis of a line chart

Tags: python, plotly

I'm plotting this dataframe:

```
    hour  counted
0      0      0.0
1      1      0.0
2      2      0.0 
3      3      0.0
4      4      0.0
5      5      0.0
6      6      0.0
7      7      0.0
8      8      0.0
9      9      0.0
10    10    792.0
11    11    792.0
12    12      0.0
13    13      0.0
14    14    594.0
15    15    198.0
16    16    198.0
17    17      0.0
18    18      0.0
19    19      0.0
20    20      0.0
21    21      0.0
22    22      0.0
23    23      0.0
```

Where:

```
x_values = df4.hour
y_values = df4.counted

layout = go.Layout(title='Line Chart for Successful Transaction per Hour', 
                    xaxis=dict(title='Hour of the day',
                                tickmode = 'linear'),
                    yaxis=dict(title='Transactions'))
```

But what actually comes out is this:

[image]

The x-axis has values of -1 and 24, when I don't actually need them. There is no "-1 hour" or "24 hour".

How do I format the plot not to show them?

**EDIT:**  the answer for Plotly is **layout_xaxis_range=[0,23]**, use it in the fig like this:

```
fig = go.Figure(data=data, layout=layout, layout_xaxis_range=[0,23])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just plot it using this code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(df4.hour,df4.count)
```

And you can define `xlim` and `ylim`

```
plt.xlim(0,24)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m5haJ.png)

Take a look at this document :https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.xlim.html

Comment: Hey, thanks, but I want to build a plotly Dashboard with it later. Will it still work if I use matplotlib?

Comment: Actually, nevermind. I found a similar option in plotly: layout_xaxis_range=[0,23].  I'm going to accept your answer though because it'll work for people who don't need to use plotly specifically and your answer helped me to search better for what I needed. Thanks!

Comment: If that is not the answer - why do you accept is as an answer? If you found a solution, you should post it as an answer and accept your own answer. [Please see here.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: Hey Mr. T, it's an answer for people who don't necessarily need to use Dash Plotly. I've added the answer for Dash Plotly as well in my original question. I think the next person looking for this will see it.